# How to rollback a http request to an api endpoint that saves data into db

Tags: java, rollback

So am writing some component tests and as far as i know the test itself should not have direct access to db or know anything about the application.

Http calls are easy to mock but what about db access in the implementation how do you mock that?

So what i did is i make a http request to an api endpoint that saves data into db, that data is used for the test purposes, the goal is to rollback that transaction after the test.

```
   @Before
  public void setupTripEvents() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    dbIntegrationMock = new DbIntegrationMock();
    setupTrips(1L, "CHARGING_STATUS_CHANGE");
    setupTrips(2L, "CHARGING_STATUS_CHANGE");
    setupTrips(3L, "DRIVER_LOGIN");
    setupTrips(4L, "DRIVER_LOGOUT");
    setupTrips(5L, "IGNITION_ON");
    setupTrips(6L, "IGNITION_OFF");
  }

private void setupTrips(long l, String triggerType) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    TripEventEntity tripEventEntity = new TripEventEntity();
    <---- data ---->
    dbIntegrationMock.saveTripEventEntity(tripEventEntity);
  }

public Void saveTripEventEntity(TripEventEntity tripEventEntity) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        return HttpClient.forService(Service.withName("componentname"))
                .send(HttpRequest.forPut("/dev/db/save/tripevententity")
                                .withPayload(tripEventEntity)
                                .withHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/json"),
                        HttpResponseType.of(Void.class, MediaType.of("application/json")))
                .whenComplete(HttpStatusToExceptionMapper::statusToException)
                .thenApply(response -> response.payload().orElse(null))
                .toCompletableFuture()
                .get();
    }

@PutMapping(value = "/db/save/tripevententity",
            produces = "application/json")
    public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<Void>> saveTripEvent(HttpEntity<TripEventEntity> request) {
        log.info("Save trip event entity...");
        return process("tripevententity", "", o -> o, request, call -> save(request));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is not a transaction so it cannot be rolled back but i can create another api that will remove this data after the test is finished